# DropDownList won't POST value by using ajax

Tags: yii

I created DropDownList and I'm trying to fill div with content and I know how to do it. But problem is that my dropdown list won't POST value.

This is code from view\index.php

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::dropDownList('parovi', '', $model->dropDownListParovi(), array
    (
        'class'=>'dropDownListLegloIzaberiPar',
        'empty'=>array('-'=>Yii::t('default', 'PAR_UZGOJNI_DNEVNIK_LEZENJA_IZABERI_PAR')),
        'ajax'=>array
        (
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/paruzgojni/ajaxIzlistajLegla'),
            'update'=>'#legla',
        ),
    )
);

?>

<div id="legla"></div>
```

And this is from controller

```
public function actionAjaxIzlistajLegla()
{
        echo $_POST['parovi'];
}
```

this AjaxIzlistaijLegla action is inside accessRules(). And it's working cause When I replace `echo $_POST['parovi'];` with `echo "Hello";` it works, it updates my div. But I don't know why it won't POST that value from drop down list.

jquery is included in head.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is I should wrap my dropDownList with CActiveForm like this

```
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'par-uzgojni-ispis-legla-form',
));

echo CHtml::dropDownList('parovi', '', $model->dropDownListParovi(), array
    (
        'class'=>'dropDownListLegloIzaberiPar',
        'empty'=>array('-'=>Yii::t('default', 'PAR_UZGOJNI_DNEVNIK_LEZENJA_IZABERI_PAR')),
        'ajax'=>array
        (
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/paruzgojni/ajaxIzlistajLegla'),
            'update'=>'#legla',
        ),
    )
);

$this->endWidget();
```

Because I didn't wrap it, it couldn't POST any data to my controller

Comment: Not really. You didnt pass any data in ajax call, thats why post is empty. Add to ajax `'data'=>'this.value'` and you'll see.